# How to create a 2D array from 1D with the algorithm specified in the description?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

Good afternoon,
I need to create a 2D array from 1D , according to the following rules:\

- The 2d array must not contain
  `[["A1", "A1"], ["A2", "A2"], ["A3", "A3"], ["A4", "A4"]...]`
- The array should not repeat, it's same for me
  `[["A1", "A2"], ["A2", "A1"], ....]`\
- For example
  Input array
  `A ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]`
  Output array
  `B [['A1' 'A2'] ['A1' 'A3']['A1' 'A4']['A2' 'A1']['A2' 'A3']['A2' 'A4']['A3' 'A1']  ['A3' 'A2'] ['A3' 'A4']['A4' 'A1'] ['A4' 'A2']['A4' 'A3']]`

I need
`[['A1' 'A2']['A1' 'A3']['A1' 'A4']['A2' 'A3']['A2' 'A4'] ['A3' 'A4']`

```
    import numpy as np
    
    x = ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
    
    arr = []
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
            if x[i] != x[j]:
                arr.append((x[i], x[j]))
    
    mylist = np.unique(arr, axis=0)
    print(mylist)
```

how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's standard library has a function that does exactly this, [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```py
from itertools import combinations

print( list(combinations(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], 2)) )
# [('A1', 'A2'), ('A1', 'A3'), ('A1', 'A4'), ('A2', 'A3'), ('A2', 'A4'), ('A3', 'A4')]
```

You can also write your own, using nested loops to iterate on the array:

```py
def all_pairs(arr):
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        for y in arr[i+1:]:
            yield (x, y)

print( list(all_pairs(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'])) )
# [('A1', 'A2'), ('A1', 'A3'), ('A1', 'A4'), ('A2', 'A3'), ('A2', 'A4'), ('A3', 'A4')]
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, even shorter, but how fast is it?
there will be calculations in a very large array

Comment: @Камаль `itertools.combinations` is as fast as it can be. If there are n elements in the array, then there are n(n-1)/2 pairs to generate. Note that `itertools.combinations` is *lazy* in the sense that it only generates the pairs as needed. As much as possible, try to use directly `combinations(...)` and not `list(combinations(...))` (calling `list` on top of it kills the laziness)

Answer (score 2):

A simple if statement to check if the tuple already exists should be all you need:

```py
    import numpy as np
    
    x = ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
    
    arr = []
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
            if x[i] != x[j]:
                if not (x[j], x[i]) in arr: // If the pair already exists, it would be the
                                            //flipped version of it
                    arr.append((x[i], x[j]))
    
    mylist = np.unique(arr, axis=0)
    print(mylist)
```